# R Markdown Creating Output Files base on Values in a Column

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, filenames

I am trying to create individual receipt documents in R Markdown. I have used the this link which has been really helpful.  https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_mail_merge.html

One thing that I need that differs from the below process is that instead of naming the files "handout1, handout2, handout3....", I need more specific file names that are saved in a column in my data set. Using the code in the linked example, I would need to include the name of the person in the file name. Is there a way to do this?

R Script:

```r
## Packages
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

## Data
personalized_info <- read.csv(file = "meeting_times.csv")

## Loop
for (i in 1:nrow(personalized_info)){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "mail_merge_handout.Rmd",
        output_format = "pdf_document",
        output_file = paste("handout_", i, ".pdf", sep=''),
        output_dir = "handouts/")
}
```

R Markdown

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
personalized_info <- read.csv("meeting_times.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
name <- personalized_info$name[i]
time <- personalized_info$meeting_time[i]
```
Dear `r name`,

Your meeting time is `r time`.

See you then!
````

Needed R Script: This code does not work

```r
## Packages
library(knitr)
library(rmarkdown)

## Data
personalized_info <- read.csv(file = "meeting_times.csv")

## Loop
for (i in 1:nrow(personalized_info)){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "mail_merge_handout.Rmd",
        output_format = "pdf_document",
        output_file = paste(personalized_info$name.pdf, sep=''), # grab the name from the name 
        column of personalized_info at i 
        output_dir = "handouts/")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use the `params` attribute in the `yaml` header as it'll make it easier to pass the data:

```
---
output: pdf_document
params:
    name: ""
    meeting_time: ""
---
Dear `r params$name`,

Your meeting time is `r params$time`.

See you then!
```

Then in `R` :

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(personalized_info)){
    rmarkdown::render(input = "mail_merge_handout.Rmd",
        output_format = "pdf_document",
        output_file = paste(personalized_info$name[i], ".pdf", sep=''),
        params = personalized_info[i,],
         # grab the name from the name column of personalized_info at i 
        output_dir = "handouts/")
}
```

#### data

```r
personalized_info <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Jane", "Marry", "Larry", "Harry"
), meeting_time = structure(c(1606418788.4989, 1606505188.4989, 
1606591588.4989, 1606677988.4989, 1606764388.4989), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: @DebbyZemlock my pleasure. mind you that accepting the answer will help future users in finding the solution, as the question will be marked as solved